# Ionic serve error after updating

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I am building a app and its near its completion, upon updating to ionic 2 it started to give me this bug:

```
/Users/Raz/Work/Ionic 2/My-World/node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts: line 1: ../@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js: No such file or directory

    npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--lab" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
    npm ERR! node v7.4.0
    npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
    npm ERR! file sh
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall spawn
    npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--lab" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
    npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--lab" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--lab" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /Users/Raz/Work/Ionic 2/My-World/npm-debug.log
    There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

I updated Npm,node,and cordova and still there are problems:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

I also did the same on other machine and the results are the same, it seems the problem could  be with ionic itself and not with npm

Comment: did you try removing your project node_module folder and running `npm install`?

Comment: Now i tried and that worked!! everything running fine now

Comment: can you move to answer so i can mark as correct?

Comment: whenever you update packages in package.json..it is the default fix for most issues :)

Comment: ok..added it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clearing your `node_modules` folder in your project.

Run `npm install`

It is the first step to fixing most issues with changes in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your version of Cordova CLI : `npm install -g cordova@latest` to the last version 6.5.0.
I believe the latest version of this framework should be running with the latest version of cordova.

Comment: ../@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js` You can try to check if this file exists too?